# What is this linear encoder from a old inkjet printer using a thin metal rod and a metallized glass plate?

Tags: sensor, identification, physics, linear

What is the working principle of this sensor ?
It was found in a canon inkjet printer from around 2000-2005. Not a fancy model, though.
The metal rod broke, as it is surprisingly fragile. It doesn't bend, it just splinters.
It looks porous on the inside, like a metal sponge.
I'm pretty sure that there were no other parts belonging to this mechanism.
Of course the rod was as long as the linear movement.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 2]

I've never seen anything like this before.
Thanks for you replies.

Comment: Where's this metallized glass plate you mention; I don't see it in any of the pictures?

Comment: The small transparent plate is glued to the black plastic slider.
In the first picture you can see the rod through it inside the slider.

Comment: ..do you mean the PCB?

Comment: There is no PCB, the part the cable is connected to is a small transparent plate.

Comment: how do you know that it is a linear encoder? ... was there a long strip of transparent mylar film?

Comment: Obvious thought is that it's a magnetic linear encoder. It would have two sensors with an offset between them. If so you'd expect magnetic poles every mm or two. Maybe you have some iron filings or a magnetic field viewing card?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany +1 ... that would explain the brittle nature of the rod

Comment: @Howie1337 put some paper between the rod and iron filings ... otherwise it may be difficult to clean up

Comment: @jsotola Thats what this question is about. There was no usual optical encoder.
Just this small slide moving along a metal rod.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Sadly I don't have anything to measure magnetic fields.
The rod does't seem to be magnetic a lot, because it doesn't interact with normal magnets.